# How to display new Yocto image option after source poky/oe-init-env

Tags: yocto, openembedded, yocto-recipe

let say i have a new yocto  image call  **stargazer-cmd**
what file should i edit so that every time i source poky/oe-init-env
it display as a build option to the user?

```
kj@kj-Aspire-V3-471G:~/stm32Yoctominimal$ source poky/oe-init-build-env  build-mp1/

### Shell environment set up for builds. ###

You can now run 'bitbake <target>'

Common targets are:
    core-image-minimal
    core-image-sato
    meta-toolchain
    meta-ide-support
```

I wish to add stargazer-cmd on top of core-image-minimal, i am not sure what to google and what is the file i need to change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me explain how to add a custom configuration to the OpenEmbedded build process.

First of all, here is the process that is done when running:

```
source poky/oe-init-build-env
```

1. The `oe-init-build-env` script initializes `OEROOT` variable to point to the location of the script itself.
2. The `oe-init-build-env` script sources another file `$OEROOT/scripts/oe-buildenv-internal` which will:

- Check if `OEROOT` is set
- Set `BUILDDIR` to your custom build directory name `$1`, or just `build` if you do not provide one
- Set `BBPATH` to the `poky/bitbake` folder
- Adds `$BBPATH/bin` and `OEROOT/scripts` to `PATH` (This will enable commands like `bitbake` and `bitbake-layers` ...)
- Export `BUILDDIR` and `PATH` to the next file

3. The `oe-init-build-env` script continues by running the final build script with:

```
TEMPLATECONF="$TEMPLATECONF" $OEROOT/scripts/oe-setup-builddir
```

4. The `oe-setup-builddir` script will:

- Check if `BUILDDIR` is set
- Create the `conf` directory under `$BUILDDIR`
- Sources a template file that will check if there is a `TEMPLATECONF` variable is set:

```
. $OEROOT/.templateconf
```

That file contains:

```
# Template settings
TEMPLATECONF=${TEMPLATECONF:-meta-poky/conf}
```

it means that if `TEMPLATECONF` variable is not set, set it to `meta-poky/conf`, and that is where the default `local.conf` and `bblayers.conf` are coming from.

- Copy `$TEMPLATECONF` to `$BUILDDIR/conf/templateconf.cfg`
- Set some variables pointing to custom `local.conf` and `bblayers.conf`:

```
OECORELAYERCONF="$TEMPLATECONF/bblayers.conf.sample"
OECORELOCALCONF="$TEMPLATECONF/local.conf.sample"
OECORENOTESCONF="$TEMPLATECONF/conf-notes.txt"
```

In the `oe-setup-builddir` there is a comment saying that `TEMPLATECONF` can point to a directory:

```
# 
# $TEMPLATECONF can point to a directory for the template local.conf & bblayers.conf
#
```

- Copy `local.conf.sample` and `bblayers.conf.sample` from `TEMPLATECONF` directory into `BUIDDIR/conf`:

```
cp -f $OECORELOCALCONF "$BUILDDIR/conf/local.conf"

sed -e "s|##OEROOT##|$OEROOT|g" \
    -e "s|##COREBASE##|$OEROOT|g" \
        $OECORELAYERCONF > "$BUILDDIR/conf/bblayers.conf"
```

Finally it will print what is inside `OECORENOTESCONF` which points to `TEMPLATECONF/conf-notes.txt`:

```
[ ! -r "$OECORENOTESCONF" ] || cat $OECORENOTESCONF
```

and by default that is located under `meta-poky/conf/conf-notes.txt`:

```
### Shell environment set up for builds. ###

You can now run 'bitbake <target>'

Common targets are:
    core-image-minimal
    core-image-sato
    meta-toolchain
    meta-ide-support

You can also run generated qemu images with a command like 'runqemu qemux86'

Other commonly useful commands are:
 - 'devtool' and 'recipetool' handle common recipe tasks
 - 'bitbake-layers' handles common layer tasks
 - 'oe-pkgdata-util' handles common target package tasks
```

So, now, after understanding all of that, here is what you can do:

1. Create a custom template directory for your project, containing:

- local.conf.sample
- bblayers.conf.sample
- conf-notes.txt

2. Do not forget to set the path to `poky` in `bblayers.conf` to `##OEROOT##` as it will be set automatically by the build script.
3. Set your custom message in `conf-notes.txt`
4. Before any new build, just set `TEMPLATECONF`:

```
TEMPLATECONF="<path/to/template-directory>" source poky/oe-init-build-env <build_name>
```

Then, you will find a build with your custom `local.conf` and `bblayers.conf` with additional file `conf/templateconf.cfg` containing the path of `TEMPLATECONF`

Answer (score 1):

`conf/conf-notes.txt` in your layer.

`OECORENOTESCONF` should point to the file.