# Running source command in wrong directory in yocto

Tags: yocto, bitbake

I am supposed to run source command in ~/yocto folder but I ran it under ~/yocto/build folder. This mistake has created another build inside build folder like - ~/yocto/build/build.
Can I delete the newly created folder? Will that cause any problem to my yocto environment?

## *USUAL OUTPUT:*

> Welcome to the PHYTEC BSP-Yocto buildsystem.
>
> Before building for the first time, you should take a look in the main
> configuration file 'conf/local.conf'. There you can tweak the build
> system settings and license configuration. For example you may have to
> accept the Freescale/NXP GPU and VPU licence for an i.MX6 board.
>
> Tested build target for this build configuration is:
>
> $ bitbake phytec-headless-image      $ bitbake phytec-qt5demo-image

## *WHAT I GOT:*

> source ../sources/poky/oe-init-build-env  You had no conf/local.conf
> file. This configuration file has therefore been created for you with
> some default values. You may wish to edit it to, for example, select a
> different MACHINE (target hardware). See conf/local.conf for more
> information as common configuration options are commented.
>
> You had no conf/bblayers.conf file. This configuration file has
> therefore been created for you with some default values. To add
> additional metadata layers into your configuration please add entries
> to conf/bblayers.conf.
>
> The Yocto Project has extensive documentation about OE including a
> reference manual which can be found at:
> https://docs.yoctoproject.org
>
> For more information about OpenEmbedded see their website:
> https://www.openembedded.org/
>
> #### Shell environment set up for builds.
>
> You can now run 'bitbake '
>
> Common targets are:
> core-image-minimal
> core-image-full-cmdline

I tried nothing yet. This is a general question and needs a short answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will not affect your main build. Just remove the new build folder.

Sourcing a build will setup up environment variables that points to that build directory.

For more details on how the build is created check my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71190705/how-to-display-new-yocto-image-option-after-source-poky-oe-init-env/71195306#71195306).